# Want to change default text on woocommerece registration form which says email already exists

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the default text of the error message on woo commerce registration form which says "account already exists with this email please login "

I would be glad to find any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to add custom PHP snippets to your WordPress site?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way, as I see it, to modify this text is using a filter that WooCommerce provides exactly for this purpose.

```
function kokab_registration_error_email_exists( $message ){

    $message = __( 'Add the text that you want to display here', 'woocommerce' );

    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', 'kokab_registration_error_email_exists');
```